# Apt Proxy similar to snapstore proxy?

Tags: apt, proxy

Hoping you can help..

I'm setting up a proxy server for our Ubuntu based machines that do not/should not have direct access to the internet so they can retrieve updates and install software.

I have successfully installed Snap Store Proxy for Snaps and it's working great.

I need a similar solution for apt packages but I'm struggling to find something that suits. I've investigated things like apt-cacher-ng, debmirror etc but I don't want to store partial or whole archives locally. In an ideal world it would operate like a "transparent" proxy, similar to snap store proxy.

Does any one have recommendedations or advice for me? It'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: A regular HTTP(S) proxy, like squid, or even small programs like 3proxy ( https://3proxy.ru ) is totally enough for all HTTP(S) based applications. It should work for Snap Store, apt etc. as long as you set it as a system-wide proxy for HTTP(S). I don't understand why do you need specialized software.
Or maybe you want to create a **local mirror** of packages repository, and not just a plain proxy?